# Ubuntu 14.04LTS on windows 8.1 virtual machine unable to login to GUI with correct password

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login, password

I am new to Linux OS learning and facing following issue.
I have installed Ubuntu 32 bit on Virtual Box 5.0. I am using HP Pavilion laptop with windows 8.1 installed.

Issue is that even after entering the correct password I am not able to login to GUI mode in Ubuntu. **I am able to login in console mode.**

When I enter the password a message `system program problem detected` pop up twice and I am returned to the enter password option again.

I have tried following

1) Even after password reset I am unable to login to GUI mode.

2)

```
    sudo apt-get purge lightdm
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install lightdm
    dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

3)  sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

I have also tried lot of other solutions given on askubuntu but I am not able to fix this issue.

Where to find the message *system program problem detected* log and how can I see the log file?

How can I fix this issue?

*Output of following command*

```
ls -l $HOME/.Xauthority
```

is

```
-rw------- 1 mukesh mukesh 62 Sep 5 23:58 /home/mukesh/.Xauthority
```

Comment: What does output of `ls -l $HOME/.Xauthority` , notice the leading dot

Comment: Also , would setting GUI to autologin be acceptable answer for you ?

Comment: @Serg during installation I set the auto login only but it is not working.should I run the command on  /home/myusername path?

Comment: Yes. I just use `$HOME` in my answers, because it's easier to understand

Comment: -rw------- 1 mukesh mukesh 62 Sep 5 23:58 /home/mukesh/.Xauthority

Comment: Hmm, nothing wrong there . . .If it was saying `root root` it would be an easy fix.  Tried switching to gdm instead of lightdm ?

Comment: @Serg  Tried switching to gdm instead of lightdm ?  How to do this I am new to linux. Do you think this may be graphics driver issue?

Comment: Graphics driver issue is quite possible, but if we can solve it without messing with graphics drivers, then it's a better way to go. Run `sudo apt-get install gdm` and when prompted chose `gdm` as default desktop manager (basically a fancy way of saying "default login screen"). Once done, restart virtual machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28821/discussion-between-muk-and-serg).

Comment: Hi Serg I did what you mentioned but now i am getting a black screen

Comment: Have you installed the virtual box guest additions? If not try http://www.binarytides.com/vbox-guest-additions-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: OK, in that case revert the change back to lightdm . Command is `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.  That's all i can suggest for now. Also, try `startx` from console or switch to different desktop environment, such as `gnome` or `xfce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally following worked for me

I installed XFCE `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` then after reboot selected this option and problem solved.